# getResourceAsStream contextInitialized

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I am writing a web application in Java using Tomcat as servlet container.
I wrote a AppLoader class implementing ServletContextListener to trap the event contextInitialized and perform some init operations.
No problem about that, but when I need to read the content of a resource (txt file) using the getResourceAsStream method, it fails and returns null.
I noticed that the same operation run in a Servlet service (so, after the web app init event) works fine and returns the file content.

It seems I can't access internal resources until the app is loaded.

How can I solve? Is there a "ready" event to trap for a web app?

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it by loading a servlet with load on Statup automatically , and call getResourceAsStream() method in init of servlet like this

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>StartupServlet</servlet-name>
   <display-name>StartupServlet</display-name>
   <servlet-class>com.myApp.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

In Servlet

```
public class StartupServlet extends HttpServlet{
@override
public void init()
{
       // do you operation here.
}

@override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
}
```

Comment: It was my starting point: my init code was initially in the init method of a loadonstartup Servlet. Then I moved it into the contextInitialized method (implementing ServletContextListener) but nothing has changed.

Comment: Sorry! I found the error... a bug of mine!
I read the content of the resource stream using a variable not yet set; the getResourceAsStream correctly returns the InputStream.
So, nothing related to the ServletContextListener or the loadOnStartup Servlet.

Again, sorry for the unnecessary post.
Next time I'll spend a debug day more before posting! :-)